# Best server for mailing application

Tags: php, email, email-server

My application is similar to a reminder service that reminds users of events that they scheduled. I'm sending emails to users through a PHP script. I'm not sending one email to multiple recipients. Each recipient receives a different message. I plan to use cron jobs every minute and expect the application to send roughly 200 individual emails in 1 hour (for a small user base that may grow).

I don't have hosting experience with this type of application. I plan to start on a shared host and move up in the future to vps or dedicated. Most shared hosts that I looked into allow 50-100 emails per hour with delays between mailings. Please kindly inform me what I should look for in web hosts for this kind of application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no direct experience with implementing a mail server, then you might well be better off starting with a cloud service, that manages submission and delivery of outgoing mail. Some examples are;

HP sendgrid;
http://sendgrid.com/pricing.html

Amazon AWS (SES);
http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

The reason that I would suggest services like this, is that you could literally have your application running in a few hours with a hosted SMTP relay, at a far lower implementation time and less cost that to run a mail server on a dedicated VPS or server instance in a datacentre.

The traditional method would be to run one of the popular mail transport agents (MTAs) such as [sendmail](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Sendmail) or postfix to handle submissions from your PHP application and then outgoing delivery to the recipient.

The more recent major distros appear to be moving to postfix as the default MTA ([CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix) 6.2  and [Ubtuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/postfix.html) 12.x) so that would appear to be the [place to start,](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/postfix.html) regarding documentation.

Obviously either Ubuntu, Centos, fedora or any of the major distros of linux have sendmail or postfix packaged in their repositories.